# Where do i create or generate a Service?

Tags: angularjs, angular, service, directory-structure

I would like to know where should I be generating an `angular2 service`? The latest documentation of `angular2` says its okay to generate a service inside the `app` folder, however, some video tutorials that I'm following has a `shared` folder pre-generated in which services are created. I could obviously create that folder but I'd like to know what's appropriate and why?

`app-name/src/app/service-name.service.ts`

OR

`app-name/src/app/shared/service-name.service.ts`

Comment: It has no effect on how your app works. It's just how you like to organize things. I create module services in the module folder and independent services in their own folders for example.

Comment: Services are meant to be shared by components, aren't they? so in that sense I was confused if creating them in a separate shared folder would make any difference. But what you said is kinda true. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am assuming that you are using **Angular-cli** folder structure. if you are not using Angular-cli than please do use it.

suppose you have **Component A and Component B**.

**Component A**: want to use service S1.

**Component B**: want to use service S2.

in that case you create S1 service in Component A folder, and S2 in Component B folder.

now assume that **Component A and Component B** want to user Service S3. in this case you should create Service in shared folder.

> summary: if you create service which is used by most of the component
>   of your app, than you should create in shared folder. or 1 component
>   using 1 service that you should create service in that particular
>   component folder.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on how you are layering in the application's architecture.
Angular 2 recommends grouping by modules/domains, hence, you have the name of each file in the domain ending with .service, .module, .pipe, .directive, etc.
Grouping the module and its related contents together within its folder will make it easy to maintain a particular module separately without changing other parts of the application. Also the routing within the module can be localized within that module.

So grouping all services under a common shared module and exporting them for use to other modules or enclosing the service to relevant module depends on the design perspective and thinking. Choose the appropriate approach based on the requirement, but always do it with maintainability in mind.

Comment: i appreciate this. Thanks!